# If $A, B, H \leq G$ such that $A \triangleleft B$ and $H \triangleleft G$, then $HA \triangleleft HB$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

There is a lemma that I'm trying to understand in my algebra class and I can't get it done. It says:

> Given $G$ a group, let $A, B, H \leq G$ be subgroups of $G$ such that $A \triangleleft B$ and $H \triangleleft G$. Then, $HA \triangleleft HB$ and $\frac{HB}{HA}$ is isomorphic to some quotient of $B/A$.

The second part is pretty ok to me and I got the morphism right away, but as much as it seems stupid, I can't get the normality done, and I've tried a lot. And it is not only this problem, I just seem to be HORRIBLE proving normality of stuff. Any tips on that?

Comment: If you already have the ismorphism, you need normality already, since $HB/HA$ is not a group otherwise. You probably gave a surjective homomorphism $HB\to B/A$ with kernel $HA$, is that right? In that case, $HA$ is automatically a normal subgroup of $HB$, since kernels of group homomorphisms are always normal.

Comment: Oh, no, what I mean is that I alredy have the isomorphism ASSUMING that $HA \triangleleft HB$, but i don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, we have
$$bab^{-1}=a_1$$
for some $a_1\in A$. Note that $a_1H=Ha_1$ and $bH=Hb$. Then
$$(Hb)Ha(b^{-1}H)=HbH(ab^{-1})H=HbHb^{-1}a_1H=Ha_1.$$